# How do you pass a variable while transitioning to another SKView in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new so bear with me.

I am transitioning to another SKscene with this code:

```
func moveToGame(game : gameType) {
    let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
    let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: transition)
}
```

Game type is the difficulty of the game, for example, easy, medium, hard.

When I go to the next scene I would like to be able to access the gameType to decide how the game is played.

How would I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why don't you use delegate?

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `UserDefaults` for storing and retrieving small amounts of data. This will also allow other scenes within the app to access data as you see fit.

**Swift 3.1 Example**

To store data in the first Scene:
`let store = UserDefaults.standard`
`store.setValue("hard", forKey: "GameType")`

To retrieve data in the next Scene:
`let store = UserDefaults.standard`
`let difficulty = store.value(forKey: "GameType")`

Comment: Please note, this solution will persist between app launches, so you will have to account for that.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The fact that it is persistent does not matter because you change the variable every time you start the app, it is not accessed more than once throughout the game.

Comment: Why set the `UserDefaults` class to a variable?  You can simply access it directly... `let difficulty = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "GameType")`

Comment: Sure, you can do this too. It was just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `userData` variable that is a associated with every SKNode, it is less code and works a lot faster than using UserDefaults.

```
func moveToGame(game : gameType) {
    let transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
    guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else {fatalError("Could not find scene")

    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    if(scene.userData == nil) {scene.userData = NSMutableDictionary()}

    scene.userData["myVariable"] = myVariable 
    self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: transition)

}
```